# WSDL adds unwanted prefix to SOAP action's paramters

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

Im facing an issue when I try to import my WSDL into Salesforce and generate APEX code from this one. The issue is targeting Salesforce, but my general question has nothing to do with Salesforce since I believe that there is a general solution to my question. When I add a targetnamespace to my second schema in the following file, which is required in Salesforce, I need to update the reference so that my request still has the valid format:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wss:querySearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Car>
            <Reg_Number></Reg_Number>
         </Car>
      </wss:querySearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My current WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="WebServiceProvider" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" version="1.0">
      <xs:import />
      <xs:element name="querySearch" type="tns:querySearch" />
      <xs:complexType name="querySearch">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Car" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearchResponse" type="tns:querySearchResponse" />
      <xs:complexType name="querySearchResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="Car" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="Car" type="Car" />
      <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Reg_Number" type="xs:string" />

        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearch">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:querySearch" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearchResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:querySearchResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:querySearch" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:querySearchResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceProviderPortBinding" type="tns:WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <soap:operation soapAction="querySearch" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebServiceProvider">
    <wsdl:port name="WebServiceProviderPort" binding="tns:WebServiceProviderPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="XXXXXXXX" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I alter my WSDL to the following (adding a targetnamespace and adding the "tns:" to the types):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="WebServiceProvider" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss" version="1.0">
      <xs:element name="Car" type="tns:Car"/>
      <xs:complexType name="Car">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Reg_Number" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearch" type="tns:querySearch"/>
      <xs:complexType name="querySearch">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Car"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="querySearchResponse" type="tns:querySearchResponse"/>
      <xs:complexType name="querySearchResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:Car"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearch">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:querySearch" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="querySearchResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:querySearchResponse" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:querySearch"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:querySearchResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WebServiceProviderPortBinding" type="tns:WebServiceProviderPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="querySearch">
      <soap:operation soapAction="querySearch"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="WebServiceProvider">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:WebServiceProviderPortBinding" name="WebServiceProviderPort">
      <soap:address location="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

It goes through Salesforce but generates the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wss="http://www.boomi.com/connector/wss">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wss:querySearch>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <wss:Car>
            <wss:Reg_Number>?</wss:Reg_Number>
         </wss:Car>
      </wss:querySearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It adds the "wss" prefix to the Car element and the input paramter in the request, which makes the request invalid. Can I solve this in some way by altering the namespaces or something like that? The wsdl is generated from Dell Boomi and hence a solution from there would be prefered but for now I am satisfied if I can alter the WSDL manually.

Ciao!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `elementFormDefault="qualified"` means that you want to get a prefix. Try with the value `unqualified`

From http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_schema.asp :

> elementFormDefault : Optional. The form for elements declared in the target namespace of this schema. The value must be "qualified" or "unqualified". Default is "unqualified". "unqualified" indicates that elements from the target namespace are not required to be qualified with the namespace prefix. "qualified" indicates that elements from the target namespace must be qualified with the namespace prefix

Comment: When I do that the prefix is removed from the parameter but still there for the Car element. This was at least on the right way, is there something I'm missing with the ref tag? The only thing I changed was the elementFormDefault="qualified" to elementFormDefault="unqualified"

Comment: You have two `<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">`, did you change the one juste before the `<xs:element name="Car" type="Car" />`?

Comment: I believe that it is solved thanks to your input, For some reason importing it directly to SoapUI gives incorrect request but when I use it through Salesforce it generates the correct request which I tested in SoapUI and got the correct response. I will mark your answer as correct and thank you, but I'll try to come back with my complete solution when I get that!